# Terminus opening to the wrong path

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

When I open Terminus the command line continually opens to the wrong path.

It automatically goes to this -

bigsky@DESKTOP-ERQRIUA:~/dapptutorial/src$

When I want to it open to

bigsky@DESKTOP-ERQRIUA:~/dapptutorial

I can change it manually using cd dapptutorial and works fine.  However, if I close out of the terminal and then open it back again it automatically reverts to ~/dapptutorial/src$.

Is there a way to specify the path here so that it opens where I want it to?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should find the absolute path of `~/dapptutorial` by this commnad:

```
cd ~/dapptutorial; passwd
```

the absolute path is some thing like this `/UserName/dapptutorial`

then add `cd /AbsolutePath` to the end of your `~/.bash_profile`. This is executed only for interactive logins and add `cd /AbsolutePath` to the end of your `~/.bashrc`.

finally it automatically goes to  `~/dapptutorial` instead of `~/dapptutorial/src`

Comment: that works! thank you!!!